# UISearchController for TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, text-files, uisearchcontroller

This is what my Table View looks like. Each cell Strings a text from a .txt 
[image]

Search Filter works fine. But When I select one of the results e.g. "How" it prints the the Content of "Hello" instead.
[image]

I'm thinking this is probably because "Hello" is programmed as the first String so it will always be the result of the first cell when clicked. I am needing help with figuring out how the search results are linked to it's own content. if that makes any sense?

Here's the code below. The code reads from .txt file swell as search the text file. the results when clicked on do not match.

import UIKit

```
class title_ViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {
var SongTitle = [String]()
var SongLyrics = [LText]()
var filteredSongs = [String]()
var resultSearchController = UISearchController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController:     nil)
    self.resultSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self

    self.resultSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    self.resultSearchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.resultSearchController.searchBar

    self.tableView.reloadData()

    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("DataBase", ofType:     "txt"){
        do {
            let stringFromFile = try String(contentsOfFile:path, encoding:     NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            var Title: [String] =     stringFromFile.componentsSeparatedByString("@")
            Title.removeAtIndex(0)
            //Seperates the Title from the Lyrics
            var t1 = Array(Title[0].componentsSeparatedByString("^"))
            t1.removeAtIndex(0)

            SongTitle = Title
            SongLyrics = [LText(LyricsText: t1)]

        }catch{
            print(error)
        }
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if self.resultSearchController.active{
        return self.filteredSongs.count
    }else{
        return self.SongTitle.count
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let Cell: AnyObject = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    Cell.textLabel?!.text = SongTitle[indexPath.row]


    if self.resultSearchController.active{
        Cell.textLabel?!.text = self.filteredSongs[indexPath.row]
    }else{
        Cell.textLabel?!.text = self.SongTitle[indexPath.row]
    }


    return Cell as! UITableViewCell

}

func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    self.filteredSongs.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c]%@", searchController.searchBar.text!)

    let array = (self.SongTitle as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
    self.filteredSongs = array as! [String]
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let indexPath: NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
    let DestViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController

    DestViewController.LyricString = SongTitle[indexPath.row]
}
}
```

any help is welcomed, thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm new at this but i have a feeling that this line has something to do with it.
`self.resultSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self`perhaps its not self. but something else. i just have no idea what it could be. I tried SongTitle instead of self but it gave me an error :(

Comment: you can perform segue manually in didSelectRowAtIndexPath by searching position of selected String from array, then you can get correct position

Comment: Thanks for that :D would you also know how I could add indexing for each cell. mmm like Alphabetical indexing but with numbers instead? @ARMV

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in your `prepareForSegue`.  You need to amend it to test whether the searchController is active.  If so, you should use `filteredSongs` to determine which song to pass to the destination VC, rather than `SongTitle`:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let indexPath: NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
    let DestViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController

    if self.resultSearchController.active {
        DestViewController.LyricString = self.filteredSongs[indexPath.row]
    }else{
        DestViewController.LyricString = self.SongTitle[indexPath.row]
    }
}
```

(As an aside, it is convention that variable names should start with a lowercase letter - `songTitle` not `SongTitle`, etc.)

Comment: Thank you, That was very helpful! :D Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can perform segue manually in didSelectRowAtIndexPath by searching position of selected String from array, then you can get correct position -

Example -

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let Cell: AnyObject = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    let str: String=  Cell.textLabel.text
    // now find str in array and then get position
    int pos = getPositionOfStringInArray(str)        

    // now perform segue for pos
    //code...

}
```