# SWIFT - NUMERIC SCROLL for UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, indexing, tablecell

In the Screen below I am trying to add a numeric indexing type of scroll if that makes any sense. I am looking to make the following cells represent page numbers so if one decides to scroll instead of search they can see which number they're up while scrolling?

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you in advance :D

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you right. You want to have pagenumbers for each cell (e.g. Hello = 1; Marry = 2; How = 3 ..... etc.)? Could you please paste your code?

Comment: Can you show sketch or some code on what you want to achieve?

Comment: Hey @AlexWoe89 the code is on a previous post --> thanks you :D http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34680811/uisearchcontroller-for-tableview/34682155#34682155

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- for display on which number user is currently you have to find out  `tblView?.visibleCells`  which returns all visible cell yue its first object to display your index (or you can use minimum indexpath.row value from visibleCells) and this method should written in ScrollViewDidEndScroll delegate method
- for going to any index(type in search box) you can use

  `let newIndex = NSIndexPath(forItem:2, inSection:0) as NSIndexPath
   tblView?.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(newIndex, atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, animated: true)`